# Is there an FAA-published handbook for Aviation Physiology?

Tags: medical, publications

The FAA has [many handbooks](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/), but I don't see one in the list dealing with aeromedical or physiology information.  Does such a handbook or advisory circular exist, or is this information only available within other handbooks such as the PHAK?

Comment: Not aware of a handbook, but they do have a GUIDE FOR AVIATION MEDICAL EXAMINERS  https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/guide.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [Introduction to Aviation Physiology](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/training/airman_education/media/IntroAviationPhys.pdf) on the FAA web site.

Comment: Hey, that's fantastic!  Where in the site navigation did you find it?  It's not in the handbooks section.

Comment: I just Google'd for "Faa handbook aviation physiology." Glad it helped.